# Resetting g:autocomplete values when blanked out

Tags: javascript, grails, autocomplete

I am using richui g:autocomplete in my grails app for some funky auto complete fields (obviously).

They typically look like so: -

```
<richui:autoComplete class="required" style="width:500px" name="autoLook[X].id" id="autoLook[X]" 
                value="" action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'form/searchAJAX')}" 
                forceSelection="true" maxResultsDisplayed="20" minQueryLength="3" onItemSelect="updateHiddenInput(id, X, 'forms')" />
```

I'm trying to work out how I can force them, when a user blanks the field out, to re-insert the previous value that was in there.  I have a function that is called when a user selects a value (updateHiddenInput) but this doesn't fire when the field is just blanked out.

Is there any way to get this to happen or will I need to implement some kind of .change() javascript instead (which seems a little rubbish to me)...?

I tried adding in the following but it doesnt seem to work: -

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
        var formID = $(this).attr("id");
        if(formID.indexOf("auto")>-1){
            alert("*" + $(this).val() +"*")  //<-- this returns **
            alert("**"+ $(this).attr("value") + "**")  //<-- this returns the old value
            var origVal= $(this).attr("value")
            alert(origVal)  <-- this alerts the original value

            if($(this).val()==""){
                $(this).val(origVal)  //<-- this does nothing :(
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Although I have just realised while testing this that if the user enters any old rubbish and tabs off the field it then picks up the rubbish value, but I don't want this so its not really a solution anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

`forceSelection="true"` force you to select value from the options given to you in drop down. You cannot enter custom value in the field. Remove `forceSelection="true"` and your `jQuery` works fine but then it accept any value(unnecessary data).

This is my code

```
<richui:autoComplete class="required" name="name[${idx}]" id="uniqueId[${idx}]"
     action="${createLinkTo('dir': 'oauthCallBack/test')}" onItemSelect="updateHiddenInput(id, this)" 
     value="${vr}" maxResultsDisplayed="20" minQueryLength="3"/>


<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
            var formID = $(this).attr("id");
            if (formID.indexOf("auto")) {
                var origVal = $(this).attr("value");
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    $(this).val(origVal);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried without the forceSelect but my jquery still doesn't work, I'm going to drop that idea now.  To get round it I'm going to instigate some kind of edit mode so users need to deliberately click a button to edit the value to stop them accidentally clearing it